# Notification of low DHCP pool in split scope setup

Tags: windows-server-2008, dhcp-server, eventviewer

In Windows Server 2008 R2, it is possible to read the Event Viewer for EventID [1020](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc726940%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) which is an indication that the DHCP pool is running low on addresses.

What if I have two DHCP servers in my domain that use an 80/20 split scope to take a /24 pool of DHCP-allocated IP addresses and split it amongst the two servers according to this [Technet Article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee405264%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)?  In this case, since the scope is split, how can I tell if the total DHCP pool, which is split amongst the two DHCP servers, is beginning to run low on address space?

Answer (score 1):

Each server will log to it's own Event log upon running out of ip addresses in it's portion of the scope. Create a Task on each server to send an email for that Event.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at this all wrong.  PowerShell is extremely slow at parsing Event Logs.

Instead, I created a script that runs the following and pipes it to a text file:

netsh server \server show mibinfo

Running the netsh command takes only a couple of seconds.  I then use a separate script to parse through the DHCP stats from the above line and email our sysadmins if a split scope is becoming full.

A similar solution:

http://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/1713-simple-ps-query-for-dhcp-statistics